# Why can't I sleep in houses that i own & why does taking things from them count as stealing?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've bought 3 houses. The first was Breezehome. Everything was normal.

I then bought Vlindrel Hall. When I first went in, I saw that everything in the house was marked as stealing if I took it and my bed was marked as owned. I went on to buy Honeyside, and it was the same situation.

I then went back to Whiterun to find that Breezehome is now corrupted in the same way. I have never had this happen before.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain you've entered the correct house?

Comment: There's probably a console command to fix this (on pc) but I certainly don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

According to TES wiki, this is a known bug, although I can't find a solution other than going back to a previous save game.

Comment: Yep. It's the right houses. :) I checked console commands but could find nothing. And unfortunately I have no previous saves. I just don't know what happened to cause this. There's got to be a solution somewhere...I hope. Thanks for the replies though.